# Windows App Certification Kit - supported API test goes wrong

Tags: hololens, app-certification-kit

I am uploading a HoloLens app. Everything is fine until the Windows App Certification Kit - supported API test goes wrong. It said `API "D3D12GetDebugInterface in d3d12.dll is not supported for this application type. UnityPlayer.dll calls this API.` which does not exist in my app.

My app is in a release configuration, and .NET Native tool chain is checked.

Answer (score 0):

When Unity 3D generates the project it creates 3 different configurations, debug, release, and master.  You  mostly packaged up "release" for the app store, you should package up "master" for the app store and you will not get that submission error.

Comment: thank you,I found out i didn't uncheck the Auto Graphic API in Unity.